# Are AJAX requests guaranteed to be fired after all external scripts are loaded?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Let's say my HTML page is loading multiple external JavaScript files, and each of them do asynchronous AJAX calls using `XMLHttpRequest`. Are the AJAX requests guaranteed to be started only after *all* the JavaScript files have been loaded?

I did a small test in a few different browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE11), and it seems to be the way that it's implemented in all of them, but is this governed by some standard?

For clarity, I mean when JavaScript files are loaded like this:

```
<script src="ajax1.js></script>
<script src="ajax2.js></script>
..etc..
```

And the JavaScript could have something like this:

```
(function() {
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.json", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log('AJAX HTTP status: ' + xmlhttp.status);
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
})();
```

Comment: do it once the `document` is `ready`, if you put the code below it will anyway execute later (until u don't have a `async` attribute in your script)

Comment: Koushik Chatterjee, even with `async` in the `<script>` tag, I observe that the JSON calls are only started after all the scripts are loaded. However, the nature of my question is purely academical and informative, not to solve a problem I am currently facing. Having said that, I can imagine that in some cases you will want to fire AJAX requests as soon as all scripts are loaded, but before the DOM is completely ready.

Comment: hmmm, sometimes your browser may not support `async`, and might be the ajax call is initiating before the script is downloaded but it is resolving after your script is downloaded!